# Reissuance of indian passport from Indian embassy in the USA

Tags: passport-renewals, vfs-global

I sent my application via courier but it was rejected:

> ineligible
> Rejection Reason: Application received is for Reissue of passport. Apply for lost damaged passport. Passport binding damaged

Shall I wait for my return courier as it has my original passport, or can I proceed with creating a new NRI application form and send it?
Will my entire payment be returned, and how?

My passport is about to expire. If I change category from reissued to damage then what will the new passport's validity be?

My current India address also has to be changed and I submitted all the documents along with my courier. Can we say that all the documents are verified and only need to change category in NRI application form along with Annexure F attached and no more changes are needed?

How will the money be refunded? I made payment on the VFS website.

I traveled with this passport many times and no one questioned about its damage.